# When to call Python's super().__init__()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass, super

(I am unable to find a reference anywhere on this matter after some Googling.)

The scenario can be clearly demonstrated with this short code sample:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, stuff):
        self.__stuff = stuff

class Y(X):
    def __init__(self, stuff):
        # Is it safe to execute statements before calling super.__init__()?
        new_stuff = self.call_another_method(stuff)
        super(Y, self).__init__(new_stuff)
```

Using CPython 3.x, the above code sample works -- assuming `call_another_method()` exists.  It this coding style generally safe, but frowned upon or considered unPythonic?  I am unable to find advice on this matter.

Why do I care?

My background comes from more traditional object oriented programming languages such as C++, C#, and Java where "super" must be called strictly as the first statement in a subclass constructor -- ignoring the zero-argument, implicit case.

If it matters, I am a young Pythoneer: 3+, please.

Comment: IIRC, in Python 3.x, you don't need to call `super(ClassName, self)` anymore, `super()` on its own works just fine.

Comment: About the only thing `super` in Java and Python have in common is the name. Java `super` is a keyword the references the (only) base class; Python `super` is a built-in function that, using its arguments, returns an object that serves as a proxy for some class in an object's method resolution order.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi: Thanks for the tip.  I'll update my code going forward!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly safe to call other things before `super()`. Python doesn't set an order, and there are plenty of use-cases for this.

Note that `super().__init__()` call is *just another expression* in Python, it is not a syntax construct. You can use `super()` outside methods too, for example, provided you pass in the right arguments.

In your case, you can omit the type and instance arguments, Python 3 will retrieve these for you when `super()` is called without arguments, because you are using it in a function defined inside a class:

```
class Y(X):
    def __init__(self, stuff):
        new_stuff = self.call_another_method(stuff)
        # super(Y, self) is implicit here:
        super().__init__(new_stuff)
```

Comment: Note that when in C++ you don't call the base's constuctor explicitly, its default constructor will be called implicitly. In Python, if you don't call it expicitly, it won't get called at all. "_Explicit is better than implicit._"

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: Ja.  Same for C# and Java (and many others).