# Calling Parent __init__()

Tags: python, class, super

I am using Python 2.6.6.

I have narrowed down my faulty code to these 2 classes:

```
class Graph(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.testme = 3
```

and

```
class StepPlot(Graph):
  def __init__(self, name):
    print("fdasfdsf")
    print(dir(super(Graph, self)))
    super(Graph, self).__init__(name)
```

Unfortunately, when I instantiate a `StepPlot` with `StepPlot('fdsfa')`, I get the error

`TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters`

Shouldn't it be able to take one parameter?

Looking at

[When to call Python's super().__init__()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946869/when-to-call-pythons-super-init)

This class organization should work.

Am I missing something fundamentally? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `super` should be the class from which it is called:

```
super(StepPlot, self).__init__(name)
```

For more information, here is a link to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).