# Does it matter if we call the superclass constructor in a subclass as first line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When using Java and C++ we must call the super class constructor as first line in the subclass.

Example:

```
public class MySubClass extends MyClass {
    public MySubClass() {
        super(); // must be first line code
        ... some code in the constructor ...
    }
}
```

When using Python we don't have to call the super class constructor as first line:

```
class MySubClass(MyClass):
    def __init__(self):
        ... some code ...
        MyClass.__init__(self)
```

Are there any differences in Python when calling the super class constructor as first line?

Comment: Well the difference is obviously the order of which you execute the code. Either you first execute the `super` call, which calls the base `__init__` and then the code in the child's `__init__` or vice-versa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to call Python's super().\_\_init\_\_()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946869/when-to-call-pythons-super-init)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there can be differences, but if you know what you are doing it is fine to do
soever.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class MySubClass(MyClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 2    
        MyClass.__init__(self)
```

vs

```
class MySubClass(MyClass):
    def __init__(self):
        MyClass.__init__(self)        
        self.a = 2
```

Result value in `self.a` will be different, but if it is intended, it may be valid code.

Comment: Why does not C/Java allow this?

Comment: Not sure about Java. C++ needs to preallocate memory. Calling c-tor later will require to redo this operation and it is not valid if the subclass already used this memory.  Python is just scripting stuff. Memory is allocated when a new var is needed.

Comment: @ghchoi Presumably the reason it's not allowed in Java is so that when some code receives a MySuperClass object, it is guaranteed that the MySuperClass constructor has been called on it. As a general rule, the only time you should have access to an object whose constructor hasn't been called is in that constructor itself.