# Order of super().__init__() call and subclass attributes

Tags: oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm learning OOP in python, and I was training polymorphism in classes ihheritances.

So, I tried the code below:

```py
class MaquinaBebida():
    
    def __init__(self):
        # Some self.methods
        self.adicionarComplemento()
        # Another self.methods
    
    # Some methods
    def adicionarComplemento(self):
        print("Complemento adicionado.")
    # Another methods

class MaquinaCha(MaquinaBebida):
    def __init__(self, cond):
        self.cond = cond
        super().__init__()
        
    def adicionarComplemento(self):
        if self.cond:
            print("Leite adicionado.")


print("MÁQUINA GERAL:\n\n\n\n")            
geral = MaquinaBebida()
print("\n\n\n\nMÁQUINA CHÁ:\n\n\n\n")
cha = MaquinaCha(True)
```

This code works fine. But, if I swap the order of "self.cond" and "super().**init**()" in the MaquinaCha class constructor, the code won't work, and will throw a "AttributeError: 'MaquinaCha' object has no attribute 'cond'". The wrong code, for comparison:

```py
# CODE

class MaquinaCha(MaquinaBebida):
    def __init__(self, cond):
        super().__init__()
        self.cond = cond

        
    def adicionarComplemento(self):
        if self.cond:
            print("Leite adicionado.")

# CODE
```

So it appears that wathever statements after super().**init** won't be executed.
Why is there this behaviour?

I tried add some variables declarations after super().**init** and didn't word too. These variables won't be interpreted.

A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946869/when-to-call-pythons-super-init), but with no specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question, that is probably easiest answered by going through the execution order. First consider the below:

```py
class MaquinaBebida:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        #self.adicionarComplemento()
    
    def adicionarComplemento(self):
        print("Complemento adicionado.")

class MaquinaCha(MaquinaBebida):
    def __init__(self, cond):
        super().__init__()
        self.cond = cond
        

    def adicionarComplemento(self):
        if self.cond:
            print("Leite adicionado.")

      
geral = MaquinaBebida()

cha = MaquinaCha(True)
cha.adicionarComplemento()
```

I've simply hashed out the line in the first init, and we see that also succeeds.

Let's look at the line in question:
`cha = MaquinaCha(True)`.
This calls the `__init__` method of MaquinaCha.

Next in execution is `super().__init__()`, which calls `self.adicionarComplemento()`.

It's important to realise what self is at this point - it refers to the latest structure, which in this case is an instance of `MaquinaCha`. This in turn calls the new method of adicionarComplemento - and here we see the bug.

The first line the new method is `if self.cond`, but self.cond isn't defined, and the script fails. One way to solve this would be as below:

```py
class MaquinaBebida:
    def __init__(self):
        MaquinaBebida.adicionarComplemento()
    
    @classmethod
    def adicionarComplemento(cls):
        print("Complemento adicionado.")

class MaquinaCha(MaquinaBebida):
    def __init__(self, cond):
        super().__init__()
        self.cond = cond
        

    def adicionarComplemento(self):
        if self.cond:
            print("Leite adicionado.")

      
geral = MaquinaBebida()

cha = MaquinaCha(True)
```